# Jumping Bitmaps

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

So I am having a very specific problem, which I feel like I should be able to figure out myself, but after 3 weeks of trying to figure out whats wrong, I'm pretty much ready to give up...

Basically I am creating an app that when you touch the screen it creates a new shape (made from a bitmap image) which then grows.

When the screen is touched again, another new shape is created which also grows.

The problem I am having is that everytime a new shape is formed, there is a "ghost" image that is not centered on the screen and flashes for a bit while it fades out. Below is the code, And I think that the problem is somewhere in the on the "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:" area, but I also think it might be in the onDraw section. If anyone has any ideas at all, anything will be helpful.

Code:

```
    package com.attempt.shape2;



    import java.util.Random;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

    public class Test extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
MainView v1;

Bitmap shape1;
Bitmap shape2;
Bitmap shape3;
Bitmap shape4;
Bitmap shape5;
Bitmap bigger1,bigger2,bigger3,bigger4;

float xOld1, yOld1, xNew1, yNew1;
float centerX1, centerY1, centerX2, centerY2,centerX3, centerY3, centerX4, centerY4;
Random generator1 = new Random();
int randomIndex1 = generator1.nextInt( 6);


//TEST STUFF
int shape1Height, bigger1Height, bigger2Height, bigger3Height, bigger4Height;
int shape1Width, bigger1Width, bigger2Width, bigger3Width, bigger4Width;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    shape1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);
    bigger1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);
    shape2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);
    bigger2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);
    shape3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);
    bigger3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);
    shape4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);
    bigger4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v1 = new MainView(this);
    v1.setOnTouchListener(this); 
    setContentView(v1);



}





@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    v1.pause();
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    v1.resume();
}


public class MainView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread t = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean isItOk = false;


    public MainView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        holder = getHolder(); 

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (isItOk == true){

            //perform canvas drawing    
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;       
            }



            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();

            onDraw(c);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

    }




    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        centerX1 = (canvas.getWidth()-bigger1.getWidth())/2;
        centerY1 = (canvas.getHeight()-bigger1.getHeight())/2;

        centerX2 = (canvas.getWidth()-bigger2.getWidth())/2;
        centerY2 = (canvas.getHeight()-bigger2.getHeight())/2;

        centerX3 = (canvas.getWidth()-bigger3.getWidth())/2;
        centerY3 = (canvas.getHeight()-bigger3.getHeight())/2;

        centerX4 = (canvas.getWidth()-bigger4.getWidth())/2;
        centerY4 = (canvas.getHeight()-bigger4.getHeight())/2;

        //bigger1Height = shape1.getHeight();
        //bigger1Width = shape1.getWidth();



        bigger1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(shape1, bigger1Width, bigger1Height, false);
        bigger2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(shape2, bigger2Width, bigger2Height, false);
        bigger3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(shape3, bigger3Width, bigger3Height, false);
        bigger4 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(shape4, bigger4Width, bigger4Height, false);



        canvas.drawARGB(100, 0, 0, 0);


        canvas.drawBitmap(bigger4, centerX4, centerY4, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bigger3, centerX3, centerY3, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bigger2, centerX2, centerY2, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bigger1, centerX1, centerY1, null);



        bigger1Height += 30;
        bigger1Width += 30;

        bigger2Height += 30;
        bigger2Width += 30;

        bigger3Height += 30;
        bigger3Width += 30;

        bigger4Height += 30;
        bigger4Width += 30;



    }

    public void pause(){

        isItOk = false;
        while(true){
            try{
                t.join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t = null;
    }

    public void resume(){
        isItOk = true;
        t =  new Thread (this);
        t.start();
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5);


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    switch(me.getAction()){

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        shape4 = shape3;
        shape3 = shape2;
        shape2 = shape1;


        bigger4Height = bigger3.getHeight();
        bigger4Width = bigger3.getWidth();

        bigger3Height = bigger2.getHeight();
        bigger3Width = bigger2.getWidth();

        bigger2Height = bigger1.getHeight();
        bigger2Width = bigger1.getWidth();

        shape1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);

        bigger1Height = 10;
        bigger1Width = 10;

        xOld1 =xNew1;
        yOld1 = yNew1;

        xNew1 = me.getX();
        yNew1 = me.getY();


        randomIndex1 = generator1.nextInt( 6 );
        int shapeChoose = randomIndex1;
        switch(shapeChoose){

            case  0:
            shape1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dia1);

            break;

            case 1:
            shape1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.skinny1);

            break;

            case  2:
            shape1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tri1);

            break;

            case  3:
            shape1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.square1);

            break;

            case  4:
            shape1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hex1);

            break;

            case  5:
            shape1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.trap1);

            break;


        }



        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        xOld1 =xNew1;
        yOld1 = yNew1;

        xNew1 = me.getX();
        yNew1 = me.getY();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        xOld1 =xNew1;
        yOld1 = yNew1;

        xNew1 = me.getX();
        yNew1 = me.getY();
        break;

    }

    return true;
}


 }
```